# If $H$ is any subgroup of $G$ and $N = \bigcap_{a\in G}a^{-1}Ha$, prove that $N \triangleleft G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

> If $H$ is any subgroup of $G$ and $N = \bigcap_{a\in G}a^{-1}Ha$, prove that $N \triangleleft G$.

The notation here $N = \bigcap_{a\in G}a^{-1}Ha$ is tripping me up and I am not sure how to handle it. I know that if I can show that left cosets of $N$ equal right cosets of $N$ or that all $a \in G$ are abelian, then that is sufficient enough to conclude that $N \triangleleft G$, but I suspect there another way that I should be approaching this problem that uses the fact that uses the intersection.

Any tips or hints in the right direction would be helpful, thanks

Comment: Which of the equivalent definitions of "normal" are you using?

Comment: This is called the _normal core_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit surprised to see all the lengthy answers here. I would certainly be discouraged if I needed to read one of those!

---

Note that $N$ is an intersection of subgroups, so $N$ is a subgroup itself.

If $g \in G$, then
$$g^{-1}N g = g^{-1}\left(\bigcap_{a \in G}a^{-1} H a\right) g = \bigcap_{a \in G} (ag)^{-1} H (ag) = N$$
so $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

---

There are some details to be filled in in the above calculation:

Second equality: Define $\phi_g: G \to G: h \mapsto g^{-1}hg$. This is a bijection, so it has the property $\phi_g(\bigcap \mathcal{C}) = \bigcap  \phi_g(\mathcal{C})$.

Third equality: Use that $G \ni a \mapsto ag$ is a bijection, so $\{ag: a \in G\}=G$.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that
$$
\bigcap_{x \in J} A_j = \{x \ | \ \forall j \in J, x \in A_j \}.
$$
We want to show that $N \triangleleft G$ ie.
$$
\forall g \in G, gN = Ng 
$$
and $N$ is a subgroup of $G$ (we see that it's an intersection of subgroups of $G$ so it's a subgroup of $G$).
Let $g \in G, n \in N$. So
$$
\forall a' \in G, n \in a'^{-1}Ha'.
$$
Take $a'=ag$. We get
$$
\forall a \in G, n \in g^{-1}a^{-1}Hag
$$
So
$$\forall a \in G, gng^{-1} \in a^{-1}Ha.
$$
This shows that
$$\forall g \in G,gNg^{-1} \subset N.$$
Thus
$$\forall g \in G, gN \subset Ng.$$
Using $g^{-1}$ we get
$$
\forall g \in G, g^{-1}N \subset Ng^{-1}
$$ so
$$\forall g \in G, Ng \subset gN.$$
Thus
$$
\forall g \in G, gN=Ng.
$$

Answer (score 0):

You need, first, to show that $N\le G$.

I will use the [two-step subgroup test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test).

Fix $H\le G$.

Since $e\in H$ because $H\le G$ and, for any $a\in G$, we have $a^{-1}ea=e$, we can conclude that

$$e\in\bigcap_{a\in G}a^{-1}Ha=N,$$

so that $N\neq\varnothing$.

Since for all $a\in G$,

$$a^{-1}Ha=\{a^{-1}ha\in G\mid h\in H\},$$

we have that $N\subseteq G$.

Let $x,y\in N$. Then $x,y\in a^{-1}Ha$ for all $a\in G$. So, fixing $a\in G$, we get $x=a^{-1}h_{a,x}a$ and $y=a^{-1}h_{a,y}a$ for some $h_{a,x},h_{a,y}\in H$.

Then

$$\begin{align}
x^{-1}&=(a^{-1}h_{a,x}a)^{-1}\\
&=a^{-1}h_{a,x}^{-1}(a^{-1})^{-1}\\
&= a^{-1}h_{a,x}^{-1}a\\
&\in a^{-1}Ha
\end{align}$$

as $h_{a,x}^{-1}\in H$, as $H\le G$. Hence $x^{-1}\in N$ since $a$ is arbitrary.

Consider

$$\begin{align}
xy&=(a^{-1}h_{a,x}a)(a^{-1}h_{a,y}a)\\
&=(a^{-1}h_{a,x})(aa^{-1})(h_{a,y}a)\\
&=a^{-1}(h_{a,x}h_{a,y})a,
\end{align}$$

which is in $a^{-1}Ha$ since $H\le G$ implies $h_{a,x}h_{a,y}\in H$. Hence $xy\in N$ as $a$ is arbitrary.

Hence $N\le G$.

---

For normality, [it suffices to show that $$z^{-1}Nz\subseteq N$$ for all $z\in G$.](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Normal_Subgroup_Test) To this end, fix $z\in G$. Then

$$\begin{align}
s\in z^{-1}Nz &\implies s\in z^{-1}\left(\bigcap_{a\in G}a^{-1}Ha\right)z\\
&\implies s\in\bigcap_{a\in G}z^{-1}(a^{-1}Ha)z\\
&\implies s\in\bigcap_{a\in G}(az)^{-1}H(az)\\
&\implies s\in\bigcap_{b\in G}b^{-1}Hb\tag{1}\\
&\implies s\in N,
\end{align}$$

where $(1)$ holds since right multiplication by a group element on a group is bijective. Hence $z^{-1}Nz\subseteq N$.

Hence $N\unlhd G$.